# Curl retrieve page without shadow dom

Tags: curl, shadow-dom

I make a script that use curl to login in a page and then retrieve the page. It works in part: it doesn't show the whole page. That page has some iframe with shadow dom content. How can I compute also these parts of the page? is there a way to retrieve also this hidden code?
This is the command that I run:

```
curl "https://example.com/portal/default.aspx" -H "Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx; DefaultPage=login.aspx" -H "Origin: https://example.com" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br" -H "Accept-Language: en-EN,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,pt;q=0.2" -H "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Cache-Control: max-age=0" -H "Referer: https://example.com/portal/login.aspx" -H "Connection: keep-alive" --data "IdLogin=user&IdPwd=&IdPwdCript=[2!>]h88RA/-VMen30:V]&ReturnTo=https://example.com/portal/" -o result.txt
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iframes are rendered by a browser, and cURL doesn't have rendering engine at all.

Try [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org) or [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org). I think that you want to script interactions with the site, so you can find wrappers around these tools for many languages.

For PHP you can try [Mink](http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/). It has drivers for Selenium or PhantomJS.

Comment: Do you know something that can help me to that server side (python or php)?

Comment: You can try [Mink](http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/) for PHP. It has drivers for Selenium or PhantomJS.